# Changing the width of an EditText when you select it

Tags: java, android

I want to make a search page with 3 text fields. Well, those text fields must expand when i select them and go back to the initial size after I am done writing. So, when I select one of the `EditText`, I must change the width and after I deselect it to go back to initial size.

Can someone help me with that?

Here is what I tried:

```
final EditText searchByName = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.search_by_name);
    searchByName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            searchByName.setWidth(250);
        }
    });
```

The problem with this solution is that the text field won't come back to initial size after I deselect it.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Yes. I am still editing, but breafly, i tried the onClickListener, but it is not the answer. After I deselect the field, it won't go back to initial size...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with onFocusChangeListener without onClick listener.. this allows you to handle the event of selection and deselection both

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onFocusChange` event to verify if the user is in the EditText or not:

```
final EditText searchByName = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.search_by_name);
     searchByName.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        /* When focus is lost check that the text field
        * has valid values.
        */
          if (hasFocus) {
              searchByName.setWidth(250);
          } else {
              searchByName.setWidth(normalSize); //Set back to normal.
            }
        }
     });
```